# Why df2 isn't showing all data of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here df2 only showing column's name but not showing column's data.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think because `9` is not string, so compare `==9` instead `=='9'`

Comment: Please do not post code and data as images. Please copy and paste the information here as text and format it as a code block or other format as needed.

Comment: And also `YEAR_ID` looks like year, e.g. `2003`. I doubt there is YEAR_ID == 9

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your data. You can include [code that creates a dataframe or the output of `print(df)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (or of a few rows and columns that allow to reproduce the example)